# Build tools and/or Package managers : Stucked Seriously

Tags: git, npm, gulp, gruntjs

With due respect to everyone,
I'm a little confused in using GruntJs... 
(the question aroused when i found Autoprefixer could help my life with those damn vendor prefixes but that's where things got complex) 
... Since its a **postprocessor** it needs a GruntJs (build tools as stated by the creator of Autoprefixer) but he wrote command in npm which is also a same thing as of Grunt (I watched it on the web being compared) **I think about it as if this is another misconception of mine, Pls clear it !!!** 
The Last but the most important : If i use any of 'em, shall i need the other in any case and/or shall i miss something ?

1- **Clear my misconception as stated earlier**

2- **If i use any of 'em, shall i need the other in any case and/or shall i miss something ?**

Thank You

Comment: Are you sure you've used google? There are plenty of tutorials out there explaining all of this.

Comment: On stackoverflow it is expected that all question askers has done sufficient research _before_ asking. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users --- You haven't demonstrated this. Which is why you have the downvotes.

Comment: That comment makes little sense. Close those tabs. Create three new ones, search for the following "git for ages 4 and up", "npm basics", and "gulp basics".

Comment: Our time isn't free, what you're asking us you can do quite easily on your own. *1* - Your question asks 4 different things. *2* - Simple explanations of these tools can be found in seconds. *3* - Use of bold and all caps is insulting, as if we can't understand you. *4* - @saifer has already answered.

Comment: "version control bullshit"? You mean git?

Comment: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/ | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ffBJ4sVUb4 | https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/ | https://www.codementor.io/jadjoubran/beginners-guide-getting-started-with-bower-package-manager-8sbwnu547 --- some helpful links

Answer (score 1):

Well, simplified explanations:

Those tools you wrote have different functions, they are all independent, you can use them alone or all (I think just that for Bower you will need Npm)

2 words expl:

**Git:** Is a tool for the version control, it helps you to take trace about what you edit on your own code, and to share it with all your team mates.

**Npm:** Is a packet manager installed with NodeJs. It helps you to download and use tools that can help you in build (Bower, less, Gulp, Grunt). Those are downloadable directly, so it is not mandatory. It creates the directory "node_modules" with all the downloaded content. It uses in your project the "package.json" file to take information.

**Bower:** Quite the same as Npm, but it helps you to keep trace of libs, you can use it to manage frameworks (angularjs, ember, bootstrap). It takes informations by "bower.json".

**Gulp and Grunt:** They have a common purpose, help you to "build" your code, making on it all you ask in their configuration files (minify, uglify, less->css, move files, concat etc), they are similar to maven (don't kill me). They uses "gruntfile.js" and "gulpfile.js"

(Sorry for bad english)